# Error with python 3 homework

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors

I have a homework on python 3 to do, using if, elif, else, .isdigit, .isalpha but i dont know why it doesn't work..

```
NumWord = ""

def str_analysis():
    if NumWord.isalpha() == True:
        print(NumWord, "is all alphabetical characters!")
    elif NumWord.isdigit() == True:
        if int(NumWord) == 100:
            print("You found the right number!")
        elif int(NumWord) >= 99:
            print(NumWord, "is a pretty big number")
        elif int(NumWord) <= 99:
            print(NumWord, "is a smaller number than expected")

while NumWord.isalnum() == False:
    NumWord = input("Enter a word or integer: ")
```

Comment: What is not working? Can you explain your problem in slightly more detail?

Comment: When i run the code, the input works, when i enter nothing, the input comes back, but if i enter something, it does nothing and stop the code

Comment: Stylistic point: don't explicitly compare to `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually call the function you wrote:

```
while NumWord.isalnum() == False:
    NumWord = input("Enter a word or integer: ")
str_analysis()
```

Comment: The `str_analysis()` call should be outdented -- you don't call it until you have a valid *alnum* as it only handles *alpha* and *num*.

Comment: Thanks @cdlane - fixed. I

Comment: @Chronoxx are you getting an error? Copied & pasted  the  code with the one additional line and it works for me. Are you indenting everything properly?

Comment: @Mark_M , i just restarted the compiler and now it works with your code ! thank you very much for your help !